# Any js lib for making the "quick add" feature in Google calendar?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have been looking around and found some libraries like jquery datepicker or xdate. But I haven't found anything that would be able to tokenize the input such as "Go to gym tomorrow at 5 pm" and turn it into a JSON input with proper date object.

I am considering to build my own from scratch but since google calendar has been around for so long, I wonder if anyone heard any library doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) would be a good start, it could figure out the "tomorrow" (see [here](http://www.datejs.com/test/relative/index.html)) and "5pm" (see [here](http://www.datejs.com/test/time/index.html)) parts, though you'd have to feed them in separately, I think.

Comment: yeah, looking for the nlp part now....seems tricky. There are some efforts on NLP in general on node.js server-side, but haven't found client-side only solution yet.